# Зачем контейнеризируют tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

Я новичок в деле java. Объясните, а зачем `tomcat` в контейнер пихают?
Какой в этом смысл, если и без контейнера, как я понимаю, его можно легко поставить на что угодно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Контейнер фиксирует операционную систему и установленные на ней софт. Разрабатываем приложение, запускаем его на tomcat внутри докер контейнера, тестируем. После тестирования этот же контейнер идет в продакшен. Такой подход гарантирует что окружающая среда приложения не будет влиять на его работу.

Опять же, проще мигрировать приложение на другие операционные системы или обновлять версию текущей. Достаточно обновить версию базового докер образа.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat не контейнезируют. Он по определению и есть контейнер - "контейнер сервлетов с открытым исходным кодом, разрабатываемый Apache Software Foundation."

Comment: А как же докер контейнеры с tomcat? Я их имею ввиду. Зачем они?